# Laravel Eloquent ORM query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, controller, laravel-5

I have been trying this mysql query to convert into laravel query but I am unable to figure it out.

```
SELECT max(a.date) as max FROM table1 a, table2 b where
a.publishing_time<='2015-02-27 12:30:00' and a.Status='1' and 
a.id=b.table1_id
```

table 1 fields are:-

```
 sl | date | publishing_time | status
```

table 2 fields are

```
 sl | table1_id | additional_fields
```

I am stucked on this please help me

Comment: are you using models or want to use the DB class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

This is laravel join query

```
 $resource = DB::table('table1')->join('table2', 'table1.id', '=', 'table2.table1_id')->where('table1.publishing_time','<=','2015-02-27 12:30:00')->where('table1.Status','1');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this Laravel query

```
DB::table('table1 as a')
->select(DB::raw('max(a.date) as max_date'))
->join('table 2 as b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.table1_id')
->where('a.publishing_time'<='2015-02-27 12:30:00')
->where(Status='1')
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
DB::table('table a as a')->join('table b as b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.table1_id')->max('a.data as max')->where('a.publishing_time', '<=', '2015-02-27 12:30:00')->where('a.status', 1)->get();
```

Comment: Duplicate from first answer